# Gradle Task - Https request - attach client certificate

Tags: ssl, gradle, client-certificates, gradle-task

I'm trying to implement a gradle task that sends a HTTPS request to my backend. For authentication, I have to attach a client certificate to the request.

Does anybody know how to do this? I'm currently using the library `http-builder-ng` but haven't figured out yet to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Well I dont know your library but is sh an option for you?
Gradle features an [Exec task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) to execute shell as task.

You could do curl there:

```
curl -v \
  --cacert ./ca.pem \
  --key ./admin-key.pem \
  --cert ./admin.pem \
  https://xxxx/api/v1/
```

In build.gradle it could look like this:
(url is a gradle project property, can be given via -P flag during build or in gradle.properties.)

```
task httpsRequest(type:Exec) {
commandLine 'sh', '-c', "curl -v --cacert ./ca.pem --key ./admin-key.pem --cert ./admin.pem '${url}'"
}
```

Comment: Might have been an option yes, but I built my own SSLContext as a solution for now.